# How to build an AEM parsys that by default places new components at the top instead of bottom?

Tags: aem

Is there a way to build/configure a parsys in AEM 6.0 such that when users drag new components from the sidekick, that the parsys will show a slot to add a new component at the top instead of the bottom (Referring to the box labeled "Drag components or assets here")?  For example, I have a parsys with a list of articles and the articles are by default shown in descending order.  When a user goes to add a new article I'd like them to by default add a new one at the top of the list in the parsys and not have to add to the bottom then re-order all the way from the bottom up.  Is this possible in AEM 6.0?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly, but to explain how parsys work:

1. Parsys is a placeholder which allow authors/editors to drag and drop
   components.
2. Editors can drop a new component before/below an existing component, which means parsys is already flexible enough to add new component anywhere.

Considering Your article list example, by forcing new component always on top, you will loose feature#2. I would recommend following options:

1. Use OOB parsys and handle this by governance.
2. or Create a component which render list of articles in descending order.

Comment: My developer had inadvertently removed the OOB ability of the parsys to drag/drop components and re-order them...so thanks for your answer, helped to convince him he had stripped the default behavior.